# ХозяИн, но хозяЕва — почему?

Tags: орфография, множественное-число, существительные

Почему так пишется: ***хозяИн*** и **хозяЕва**?

Comment: **Хозяин** — тюркское слово (*кожаИн* — каз., *хожаИн* — тат.); множественное — *хожайлА*. В русском языке переход ударения произошёл, но не будет неправильным произношение ***хозяевА*,** что фонетически схоже с ***кожайлА*.**

Answer (score 2):

Для этого существительного используются нестандартные формы образования множественного числа: *хозяин - хозяева,* основа усекается на суффикс ИН и далее наращивается суффикс множественного числа ЕВ+А.